# What height to attach SWA cable to brickwork

Tags: cables

I am about to fit SWA (Steel Wire Armoured) cable to the outside of my house to supply power for a garden office. The cable is mostly underground but will run along the back wall of my house for a few metres. The ground below the wall is grass. Is it best to route the cable as low down as possible, or is there some benefit in screwing the clips above the damp proof course layer? The area will be subject to lawnmower and strimmer usage.

I'm based in the UK, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Where are you in the world. Electrical code varies by location, for example most cables need protection below 8’ in the US to get a good answer your location adding that will be helpful.